# Error connecting Google AutoML API with API KEY

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-vision, google-vision, google-cloud-automl

I am trying to connect in the API using the link below by Postman

```
POST https://automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*****/locations/us-central1/models/*****:predict?key=*****
```

But I am getting the message below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

KEY is authorized to use the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a limited number of Google APIs can be used via an API key, look [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).
I don't think AutoML APIs support key-based access.

For Postman, you can generate an access token using the [OAuth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), but if you are going to develop an integration, service account credentials is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a bearer token via the gcloud command. First authenticate an account locally (service account or not) and make that account active. Then run `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

For cURL, setting the Authorization header field looks like this:

`-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`